# HTML Link only opens if I open in new tab

Tags: html, css

I've created a basic html page with a top navbar which has one of the code snippets as follows

```html
<a href="./team.html" class="hover-effect scroll">
    <span>
        <span><b>THE TEAM</b></span>
        <span><b>THE TEAM</b></span>
        <span></span>
    </span>
</a>
```

Now for reasons unknown to me, when I click on the link normally nothing happens. When I click on the scroll wheel to open a new tab, nothing happens. However, when I right click and click on open a new tab then it works.

Also the following works perfectly if on index page:

```html
<a href="./index.html#about" class="hover-effect scroll">
    <span>
        <span><b>ABOUT</b></span>
        <span><b>ABOUT</b></span>
        <span></span>
    </span>
</a>
```

But only when I'm on the index page. Not on any other page.
Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I can't see the error here. If I execute this, it work. What is your browser say if you get with your mouse over the link? Does it say something like this: `www.yoursite.com/index.html`?

Comment: im running on localhost so it says `localhost/team.html`

Comment: Did you tried it with a different browser? What's gonna happen if you click on this link? Just nothing and you stay on your index page or something else?

Comment: I tried on Chrome, Firefox and Edge. It just stays on the current page its on

Comment: I edited your question. If you run the code snippet, does it work here? So do you get a 404 Error?

Comment: also , can you kindly disable javascript in your browser and try it out once !

Comment: Try to remove `./` at the beginning of your path. If not helps then try full path with protocol. If you are on localhost use: `http://localhost/index.html#about`.

Comment: @PatrickMlr yes it gives a 404 error

Comment: @luciferous did that, no effect

Comment: @JCDenton Looks like you have a configuration on your localhost that will disable something. Do you have a `.htaccess`?